# Get Comma Delimited List of Initials of Items in Directory?

Tags: shell, text-processing, ls

How can I generate a comma-delimited, case-insensitive list of the first characters of the names of the files and directories in a directory, excluding initial "." items, without duplicates?  I don't need it to be recursive - just one level deep.

For example, from a directory where ls produces…

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 10 bryan  staff   340B Jun  6 15:32 .
drwxrwx---@ 27 bryan  staff   918B Jun  6 15:29 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 bryan  staff   6.0K Jun  6 15:32 .secrets
drwxr-xr-x+  2 bryan  staff    68B Jun  6 15:30 Apoptosis
drwxr-xr-x+  2 bryan  staff    68B Jun  6 15:32 Fanciful Notions
-rwxr-x---@  1 bryan  staff   351B Jun  2 16:57 Pungent
-rwxr-x---@  1 bryan  staff   351B Jun  2 16:57 Zoophilia
-rwxr-x---@  1 bryan  staff   351B Jun  2 16:57 addled_symbionts
-rwxr-x---@  1 bryan  staff   351B Jun  2 16:57 putrid
drwxr-xr-x+  2 bryan  staff    68B Jun  6 15:30 zuegma mandegreen
```

…I'd like to return…

```
a, f, p, z
```

I'm using BSD, am a nube, and can't quite make this work.

Comment: For what purpose? Is this an assignment?

Comment: Nope, not any sort of assignment.  (That would be cheating!)  I'm arbitrarily parsing directory contents into progress-reportable units of work.

Comment: Egaads…  I'm overwhelmed by the plethora of answers.  Thanks, everyone, for your generosity.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with the shell/coreutils:

```
for f in *; do printf "%s\n"  "${f:0:1}" ; done | 
    tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sort | uniq | paste -d, -s
```

The `${var:X:Y}` syntax prints a Y-character long substring of variable `$var` starting at position `X`

Comment: Thanks.  I went with Mapio's approach, but learned something from reading yours that I'm sure will come in handy eventually.

Comment: That should be `echo "${f:0:1}"`, in case there is a file whose name begins with `*`.

Answer (score 3):

You can go with

```
ls -1 |  cut -b1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort -u | paste -d, -s
```

where:

- `ls -1` gives you a list of filenames (one per line),
- `cut -b1` takes just the first char per line,
- `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` turns all to lower cap,
- `sort -u` removes the duplicate, and
- `paste -d, -s` puts the lines together using `,` as a separator.

Comment: Nice one but note that it will break on file names with newlines. Also, `-u` is a GNU flag, I don't think that BSD `sort` will have it. Use `uniq` instead.

Comment: @terdon; `sort -u` goes back until at least SystemV R4 in the early 1980's; it certainly is **no** GNUism.

Comment: @terdon: I've tested it on OSX and GNU/Linux (I don't have a BSD machine at hand), but if I create a file with a newline in the name `ls` returns the newline as a `?` – so it seems my solution will not break. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Janis and Mapio I stand corrected,  I thought it was GNU. As for the newline, yes ls will show it as a `? ` but if you parse it it will be a newline. `foo\nbar` will return an f and a b.

Comment: Thank you - particularly for the annotations..

I went with 'ls -1ash | cut -c 59 | sort -fu | paste -s -d , -' to avoid some complications with odd ball ls environment variables on some of our hosts.

Comment: [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @terdon - parse it? Do you mean that `ls` defaults to `-q` mode when writing to a terminal but not otherwise? In this case the only harm a newline can have is at the head of a line. And in that case what would you print for that listing anyway? In stead if you use `ls -1q` with a POSIX `ls` you will get one listing per line whether you parse it or not. It just occurred to me that `ls` also does `-m`, though.

Comment: @Bryan If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record; a *shell only* solution with `ksh` (`ksh93` required here) or (newer versions of) `bash` if all the external processes shall be avoided:

```
typeset -A a
for file in *
do typeset -l f=${file:0:1} ; a+=( [$f]= )
done
list=$( printf ", %s" "${!a[@]}" )
printf "%s" "${list#, }"
```

Comment: Note to readers: this is ksh syntax. For bash, change "typeset" to "declare"

Comment: Note: Newer versions of `bash` support `typeset`.

Comment: hmm, true, but: `help typeset` returns `... Set variable values and attributes. Obsolete.  See `help declare'`

Comment: That's rather strange; declared obsolete shortly after it had been introduced. - I was under the impression the shell developers tried to converge the design of their matching features.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf %c,\\n * | 
sort -fu        |
dd cbs=8 conv=lcase,block
```

...will...

1. print the first character of every argument matched in the `*` glob followed by a comma and a `\n`ewline to stdout
2. sort that stream while ignoring case and squeezing duplicates
3. fold that stream into a single line of 8 *(space-padded)* chars per record while simultaneously converting all upper-case chars to lower-case

I guess I have some weird filenames in this dir that need removing, but ...

```
0,      1,      =,      a,      b,      c,      d,      e,      f,      g,      h,      i,      k,      l,      m,      n,      o,      p,      q,      r,      s,      t,      w,      x,      y,      z,      _,      ~,      
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
224 bytes (224 B) copied, 7.2813e-05 s, 3.1 MB/s
```

The last bit is `dd`'s processing report. You can see it's pretty fast. You can drop the report with `2>/dev/null` though as you like.

Optionally add another `dd` or `fold` or something to the tail of the pipeline to reign in  the line length. Like:

```
CMD | dd cbs=80 conv=unblock
```

...or...

```
CMD | fold -w80
```

...which differ only a little - `dd` will strip trailing spaces from the folded results at 80 byte boundaries - which should render at maximum 10 results per line at 74 bytes per line, while `fold` will interpret chars as chars *(not bytes)* but also interpret backspaces and tabs in column-sensitive ways without stripping trailing spaces.

`dd`'s twice folded results as passed through `sed -n l`:

```
0,      1,      =,      a,      b,      c,      d,      e,      f,      g,$
h,      i,      k,      l,      m,      n,      o,      p,      q,      r,$
s,      t,      w,      x,      y,      z,      _,      ~,$
```

Answer (score 0):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  OFS = ", "
  for (z in ARGV)
    y[tolower(substr(ARGV[z], 1, 1))]
  for (x in y)
    $(++w) = x
  print
}
```

Call like this

```
hello.awk *
```